# Click event on a button which was created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am creating a button using javascipt like below:

```
 "<div class='row'><button id='rkeys'>Related<button></div></div>"

  $('#search_results').append(html_result)
```

And below that I have the functions which is waiting for a click event on '#rkeys' id, but nothing happens when I press that button.

```
 related_keys = ->
   console.log('click')
 $('#rkeys').on 'click', related_keys
```

What can I do to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need event delegation:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#search_results').on('click','#rkeys',function(){
    //click event code.
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
related_keys = ->
   console.log('click')
 $('#search_results').on 'click','button', related_keys
```